# Unable to access resource file using relative path

Tags: jmeter, pycharm, robotframework

I have created few variables under resource file and if i try to access with complete absolute path i am able to access the variables under resource file but if i use relative path it is not working.

Below is the screenshot of resource file (tried with changing format to .txt , .robot , .resources)
[image]

Below is the testcase file from where i am tryng to access resource file

[image]

Comment: Please hide/obscure the content of the resource file, it has sensitive information.

Comment: my bad..thank you soooo much for highlighting..i have replaced the image

Comment: I would strongly suggest changing the creds, they should now be considered compromised.

Comment: sure will do that ..thanks once again :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using relative imports, they are based off the location of the the file you are importing in.

As the Collections.robot is in the **other_dirs/venv/Test/Collection/** directory, and the resource one in **other_dirs/venv/resources /Txt/**, the correct relative import path is:

```
Resource       ../../resources/Txt/Resource.robot
```

---

Side note - why are you storing your sources in the `venv` dir? This looks like the python virtual environment you are using, and as such is managed by it; it often is also in git ignore, etc. That just looks like an incorrect practice.

Answer (score 2):

Your "relative" path is relative to **Collections.robot file**, you need to go couple of levels up, something like:

```
../../resources/Txt/Resource.robot
```

where:

- first `..` moves you to Test folder
- second `..` moves you to `venv` folder
- and under `venv` folder you have this `resources`

Also I don't think using Robot framework is the best way of running a JMeter test, looking at [release history of the JMeter library](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-jmeterlibrary/1.0/#history) it was updated 4 years ago and since then several versions of JMeter released, for instance [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) which had a lot of breaking changes so I would rather recommend switching to [Process library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html) and run JMeter in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)